# Using BeautifulSoup - Webpage is updating more frequently than my extracted text

Tags: python

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract stock prices, and I am testing the code with a Cryptocoin called Ethereum (https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/). I feel compelled to mention that I do not intend to work withcryptocurrencies, they are just the most volatile and open 24/7 which is good for late night coding! Anyway.. when I run the below code, the price does change occasionally, but maybe only twice in the 250 seconds that I am running the code for. I have a 2nd screen, so I have been keeping an eye on when the printout changes, and when the webpage updates; unfortunately the two do not match at all as the webpage changes every few seconds, but the output from my code stays the same.

Could anyone explain to me why this is? I should finally add that I am not a professional programmer, nor do I have years of experience with Python, so any explanation might need to omit some more "technical" terms.

Thanks!

The purpose of the program is to keep track of the stock's price and run a simulation of a trading strategy. I do intend to write this to some CSV file in future, for now however I am just happy printing to the console to check it works. It should print the correct (according to the website) stock price every 2 seconds.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

i = 2

while i<=500:
    page = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    string_ = soup.find("div", {"class":"priceValue"}).get_text()
    print(string_)
    i += 2
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: You should consider using their API for reliable data.
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide
Futhermore, your goal maybe better achieved using a connection to a websocket instead of making multiple requests.

Comment: @1extralime - Thanks for the information, I will take a look at that approach. Could I ask though, why would the code not be working properly if I am creating a new page reference at each start of my for loop?